# Export SSRS report to CSV

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, export, csv

I would like to export an SSRS report to a CSV file. Sounds simple, but I do not know how to add double quotes to the column headers in the exported CSV file. For example:

```
"UserName"|"UserAdd"
"Mike"|"Some Address"
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have seen this work is by adding the double quotes inside the report yourself, but that can be a bit tedious if you have many textboxes and many reports.

Something like this should work though:

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV",  """" & CStr(Fields!MyField.Value) & """", Fields!MyField.Value)
```

This code checks to see if it's being rendered to csv and adds the quotes if that's the case.

Comment: This does not work (at least with my ReportServerConfig). Using `=iif(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV", """" & "Value" & """", "Value")` returns as `"""Value"""`

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating the column name (including double quotes) in square brackets, like `["ColumnName"]`.

This SQL query works in SSMS, so it might work for you too:

```
SELECT ["ColumnName"] = ColumnData
FROM Table_ABC
```